# How to deal with path management in AngularJS apps

Tags: angularjs, path

I'm interested in finding out of there's a smart way of managing paths (as in URLs) for various parts of the application.

If you have them in HTML (`href` attributes), controllers and services (`$location.path()` calls) it's super messy to change a URL from say /login to /auth. You have to go through all your JS and HTML files looking for references to that.

How should this be done?
I'm thinking of a paths object as an `angular.constant` which gets injected in scope for HTML files to use and referenced as JS objects in controllers and services in order to have a single place to keep them.

Would that be a good way of doing this? Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer the way [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) handles that. The routes are named, and therefore can be referenced by name, and passed parameters like using them as a function. See examples here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem you are describing.  I had hard-coded urls all over in my app and changing anything was a nightmare.  So I decided to come up with a good solution.  And here's what I finally decided on.  It might not be perfect, but I haven't had any problems with it so far.  PS.  My app is huge, so there are a lot of urls to keep track of.

```
.constant('RoutePaths', {
    login: {
        login: '/login',
        eula: '/login/eula',
        noSubscription: '/no-subscription',
        myAccount: '/my-account',
        createAccount: '/my-account/create',
        createAccountFromXID: '/my-account/update',
        ...
        // more routes here
    },
    conreg: {
        compInfo: '/bronze/companyInfo',
        serviceArea: '/bronze/serviceArea',
        licenses: '/bronze/licenses',
        insuranceBonds: '/bronze/insuranceAndBonds',
        certifiedReviews: '/silver/certifiedReviews',
        certifications: '/silver/certifications',
        yearsAndBBB: '/silver/yearsAndBBB',
        ...
        // more routes here
    },
    ....
    // more objects here
}
```

Because I've declared this `RoutePaths` object as a `constant`, I can now use this in my app's `config` module in conjunction with the built-in `$routeProvider` as such:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','RoutePaths', function($routeProvider, RoutePaths){
    var login = RoutePaths.login;
    $routeProvider
        .when(login.login, {templateUrl: '../partials/login/login.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl'})
        .when(login.eula, {templateUrl: '../partials/login/eula.html', controller: 'EulaCtrl'})
        .when(login.myAccount, {templateUrl: '../partials/login/account.html', controller: 'AccountCtrl'})
        ...
        // more routes declared here
}]);
```

And you can inject the same `RoutePaths` dependency into any controllers, services, factories, filters, etc that you need to:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','RoutePaths', function($scope, RoutePaths){
    $scope.paths = RoutePaths.login;
    ...
}]);
```

And in your views, you can bind to those paths using:

```
<a ng-href="{{paths.myAccount}}">My Account</a>
```

And then any changes I have to make, I can just make them within the `RoutePaths` constant and they are updated everywhere in my app.  It works pretty well for my purposes.  Were you looking for something more robust or does that work for you?

Comment: Lovely. Would you say that's the "right way" of doing this in Angular?

Comment: Its the best "angular" way of doing that I know of.  It's modular, provides dependency injection, it's testable, etc.  So, as far as I know, yes.

Comment: Thank you. [extra chars]

Answer (score 2):

This might help, from angular-ui/ui-router:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

I use the ui-router almost exclusively now so I forget how angular's own router deals with this issue.

Comment: I'm not using the ui-router. Angular just needs strings for the when() method on the $routeProvider.

Comment: If you really can't use ui-router then I suppose $rootScope params for your paths that are used in the $routeProvider and the template? I'm guessing really though, just use ui-router if you want minimal effort for maximum payback, you get the advantage of nested routes as well...